# How to get the size of a static library?

Tags: gcc, static-libraries

I am compiling a static library written in C and compiled with the GCC and I got a `libopt_req.a` file.
I want to know the size of the compiled library (.text, .data etc).

Comment: What research did you do? There's literally a command named `size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found the `size` command which works nicely.